# SQL returning two rows matching different criteria into separate columns

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble adjusting an SQL query where I need to take two rows that match similar criteria and give them each a column. Here is an example of the table I am querying:

| SEQNO | PICKSLIPNO | EVENT_TYPE | DATETIME | SUBJECT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20000 | 10045 | H | 2021-09-30 8:21 | Picking Slip Created |
| 20001 | 10045 | P | 2021-09-30 8:22 |  |
| 20002 | 10045 | I | 2021-09-30 8:25 |  |
| 20003 | 10045 | H | 2021-09-30 11:22 | Order delivered |

And the result I would like:

| PICKSLIPNO | PickingDate | DeliveryDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10045 | 2021-09-30 8:21 | 2021-09-30 11:22 |
| 10052 | 2021-09-30 8:25 | 2021-09-30 10:32 |
| 10122 | 2021-09-30 7:32 | 2021-09-30 13:54 |

I am trying query and return both the datetimes of picking slip creation and order delivery in two separate columns on the same row for each pickingslipno between a certain date range. I've tried the following code which worked perfectly when I only query one PickslipNo. However, as soon as I try querying a wider range I get an error that my subqueries are returning multiple results.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT DATETIME
    FROM SALESORDHIST
    WHERE SUBJECT LIKE 'Picking Slip Created'
    AND DATETIME >= GETDATE()-5
    AND DATETIME <= GETDATE()
) AS PickingDate,
(
    SELECT DATETIME
    FROM SALESORDHIST
    WHERE SUBJECT LIKE 'Order delivered'
    AND DATETIME >= GETDATE()-5
    AND DATETIME <= GETDATE()
) AS DeliveryDate
FROM SALESORDHIST
```

Apologies if this doesn't make sense and I appreciate you taking the time to read this/help out.

Comment: Can't see the delivery date "11:22" for 10045...

Comment: Sorry, I did up a dummy table and didn't bother to proofread it. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select the data for the order slip create and then left join to the delivery -- like this:

```
SELECT SLIP.PICKSLIPNO , SLIP.DATETIME AS PickingDate, DEL.DATETIME as DeliveryDate
FROM SALESORDHIST SLIP
LEFT JOIN SALESORDHIST DEL ON SLIP.PICKSLIPNO = DEL.PICKSLIPNO 
                           AND DEL.SUBJECT LIKE 'Order delivered'
WHERE SLIP.SUBJECT LIKE 'Picking Slip Created'
```

Comment: you're welcome @DanOaky